Could not transfer artifact from/to central: Broken pipe
Getting this issue when trying to create a Maven web app. I've looked around on stack overflow and tried many possibilities, but none seem to work. Here's my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>

I'm not on company network or anything, so I don't believe I need a proxy. I've tried running "mvn clean install -U", checked my PATH variable, reloading the project, and several other things. I am on mac M1 Sonoma and using IntelliJ CE. Any help is appreciated!

Why do you override central repository?
output of mvn -v and errors from mvn clean install -U -e can help to understand your issue

You can try update your maven configuration.
You can update settings.xml file in the Maven conf directory (usually located at /path/to/maven/conf/settings.xml) or you can create settings.xml if not present.
Example Locations of settings.xml
Windows: C:\Users\YourUsername\.m2\settings.xml

macOS: /Users/YourUsername/.m2/settings.xml

Linux: /home/YourUsername/.m2/settings.xml

and remove the repositories config from pom.xml
add setting.xml file
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  
  <mirrors>
    <!-- Mirror for Maven Central -->
    <mirror>
      <id>central</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  
  
</settings>


I tried that but it gives me the same error.

can you try changing version of parent

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.0


I tried as you said, but it gives the same error. Is there somewhere else I need to change? Thank you for your help

can you share you github url for project?

also try clean you maven repo
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot

after cleaning maven repo try force update
mvn clean install -U

This works on my machine, there is no error in your project config

please clean you maven repo and try again rm -rf ~/.m2

are you running this command from you IDE?

What should I do after rm -rf ~/.m2? It still doesn't seem to work for me, could it be something to do with settings.xml or my network?

Yes, but I tried it with terminal and it gives the same error

can you access this in your browser ? https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Yes, it is not blocked

add setting.xml file and try again
nano ~/.m2/settings.xml

I have added content of setting.xml in answer

I copied your settings.xml, and ran mvn clean install -U, still the same issue. Do you have any other ideas? And thank you again

what is output of mvn -v

Says I am using apache maven 3.9.7

and also give me the output of mvn clean install -X

can you show me complete output of mvn -v

can you show me complete out of mvn -v ?

I also added the mvn clean install -X log to the git repo

Also i want complete output of command mvn clean install -X, you can put output in your github repo file

yes I added it as log.txt

if you put output in git i'll check tomorrow

Ok thank you, let me know when you can

I updated setting.xml, please update and try

take updated now?

are you checking?

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I ran mvn clean install -U

can you try one last thing, i updated setting.xml and send me output of mvn clean install -X on github, i will check tomorrow

Ok, I added the new log on github as log.txt, thank you

Any new updates?

Resolved. It was my McAfee content filter that was blocking connection to central repo. I had to disable it in system settings
